# Not able to login to opensearch Dashboard on Windows machine

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am using Filebeat-opensearch-Opensearch Dashboard very first time. And I am using it only on local Windows machine.

I am able to launch Filebeat,Opensearch[http://localhost:9200/] and Opensearch-dashboards[http://localhost:5601/app/login?]. But not able to login to Opensearch Dashboard.

When I enter credentials admin/admin, It says, **"[error][plugins][securityDashboards] Failed authentication: Error: no handler found for uri [/_plugins/_security/authinfo] and method [GET]"**.

**opensearch-dashboard.yml:**

```
server.port: 5601
opensearch.hosts: [http://localhost:9200]
opensearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
opensearch.username: admin
opensearch.password: admin
opensearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [authorization, securitytenant]

opensearch_security.multitenancy.enabled: false
opensearch_security.cookie.secure: false
```

**opensearch.yml:**

```
 plugins.security.disabled: true
```

*Only 1 entry is there in opensearch.yml file.*

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with disable security here what I have done.

1. Delete the OpenSearch-xxx/plugins/opensearch-security folder on all nodes.
2. Delete all `plugins.security.*` configuration entries from `opensearch.yml` but keep `plugins.security.disabled: true`
3. comment/remove all `opensearch_security.` entries from `opensearch-dashboard.yml`
4. You might need to remove security plugin while running opensearch.bat file by running `bin/opensearch-dashboards-plugin remove securityDashboards`

follow these official docs for more info...
https://opensearch.org/docs/1.1/dashboards/install/plugins#remove-plugins

https://opensearch.org/docs/1.1/security-plugin/configuration/disable/

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable below mentioned config variable by setting it to `true`. This will by default enable opensearch dashboard without the login screen.

```
DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN=true
```

Also note with this changes, hosts set under opensearch dashboard should be `'http'` and not `'https'`, like this -

```
OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["http://opensearch-node1:9200","http://opensearch-node2:9200"]
```

Answer (score -4):

If you are not able to login to the Opensearch Dashboard on a Windows machine, then here are a few things that you can try:

1. Make sure that you have the correct username and password.
2. Check if the Opensearch Dashboard service is running on your machine.
3. Check if your internet connection is working properly.
4. If you are using a proxy server, make sure it is configured correctly for the Opensearch Dashboard.
5. Try restarting your machine and try to login again.
6. Try using a different web browser and try to login again.
7. If all else fails, try reinstalling the Opensearch Dashboard application on your machine.

Comment: I don't know, is the username /password correct or not? I am just using the one specified in .yml. It is admin/admin.  I have checked Opensearch Dashboard is running, that's why I am able to see login screen of Opensearch dashboard. Internet connection is fine. No proxy server. Checked on diff. browser. admin/admin credentials not working.